# Word Web Add-in: Sorry, but we can't start this app because it isn't set up properly

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I try to deploy my Word web add-on that created by Visual Studio 2017 using the Slideloading method.

When I upload the manifest file the message it gives to me seems fine saying:

> **Get started with your sample add-in!**
>   Your sample add-in loaded successfully. Go to the HOME tab and click 'Show Taskpane' button to get started.

but when I go to use it, it fails saying:

> **Add-in Error** Sorry, but we can't start this app because it isn't set up properly.

Although I followed the sideloading method well and changed the source location default value to: `<SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/App/Home/Home.html" />`

Besides this method worked well by OfficeApp manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created your add-in using Visual Studio and just want to test it, you can run/load the add-in simply by using `F5` (**Start**) within the Visual Studio project. When you press `F5` to start the project, Visual Studio will automatically host the add-in on your local IIS server and will open Word with the **Show Taskpane** button visible in the **Home** tab. The [Word add-in quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/word-quickstart?tabs=visual-studio) describes this process in more detail. (Note: if you're using Visual Studio to run the add-in like I've described here, you shouldn't modify the `localhost` port number within the `DefaultValue` attribute of the `SourceLocation` element in the manifest.)

If you created your add-in using Visual Studio but want to be able to run it by using the [Sideloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins) technique (i.e., *without using Visual Studio*), then you'll need to deploy the web application portion of the add-in to a web server. In your post, you say that you've specified `https://localhost:44300/App/Home/Home.html` as the initial page of your add-in. If you navigate to that URL using a web browser, does the page load successfully (with no certificate errors)? If not, that could indicate a problem with your web app -- for example, perhaps there is no web server running at `localhost:44300`, or perhaps the web server is running but there is no such path as `App/Home/Home.html`, or perhaps the web server is running and that is a valid path but the add-in web app isn't SSL-secured.